# When trying to remove just one element in a nested numpy array the whole subarray gets deleted

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array (temp_X) like:

> [ [[23,34,45,56],[34,45,67,78],[**23**,45,67,78]],
>
> [[12,43,65,43],[23,54,67,87],[**12**,32,34,43]],
>
> [[43,45,86,23],[23,45,56,23],[**12**,23,65,34]] ]

I want to remove the 1st element of each 3rd sub-array (highlighted values).

shown below is the code that i tried:

```
for i in range(len(temp_X)):
    temp_X = np.delete(temp_X[i][(len(temp_X[i]) - 1)], [0])
```

Somehow when I run the code the whole array gets deleted except for 3 values. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, the expected output won't be a regular array, because you would end up with variable number of elements in each subarray?

Comment: This isn't a 'nested array'.  That's a list concept.  This is a 3d array, with shape (3,3,4).  You could slice off a 'column' but it would affect all subarrays, e.g. `temp_X[:,:,1:]` (producing (3,3,3)).

Comment: @Divakar yes after doing the removing part. I intend on flattening each sub-array (ex: [[23,34,45,56],[34,45,67,78],[45,67,78]] into [23,34,45,56,34,45,67,78,45,67,78])   later.

Comment: You should be reshaping (to 2d), and then removing one column.  That maintains the regular shape of an array.

Answer (score 2):

With `a` as the 3D input array, here's one way -

```
m = np.prod(a.shape[1:])
n = m-a.shape[-1]
out = a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)[:,np.r_[:n,n+1:m]]
```

Alternative to last step with boolean-indexing -

```
out = a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)[:,np.arange(m)!=n]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [285]: a
Out[285]: 
array([[[23, 34, 45, 56],
        [34, 45, 67, 78],
        [23, 45, 67, 78]],

       [[12, 43, 65, 43],
        [23, 54, 67, 87],
        [12, 32, 34, 43]],

       [[43, 45, 86, 23],
        [23, 45, 56, 23],
        [12, 23, 65, 34]]])

In [286]: out
Out[286]: 
array([[23, 34, 45, 56, 34, 45, 67, 78, 45, 67, 78],
       [12, 43, 65, 43, 23, 54, 67, 87, 32, 34, 43],
       [43, 45, 86, 23, 23, 45, 56, 23, 23, 65, 34]])
```

Here's another with mask creation to mask along the last two axes -

```
mask = np.ones(a.shape[-2:],dtype=bool)
mask[-1,0] = 0
out = np.moveaxis(a,0,-1)[mask].T
```